# nmcli is not working in Kickstart script

Tags: centos7, kickstart, rhel7, networkmanager

I have the following commands in a Kickstart post-install script:

```
firewall-offline-cmd --new-zone=management
firewall-offline-cmd --zone=management --add-service=ssh --add-service=snmp
firewall-offline-cmd --zone=management --change-interface=eth1
nmcli device modify eth1 connection.zone management
```

From my reading it seems that `firewalld` can't make these changes when NetworkManager is in the picture, so I added in the `nmcli` command to change the zone. But it is not taking effect. After the install is complete and the server reboots, the interface remains in the default zone. After that I can then run the `nmcli` command and it will take effect.

I can't find anything online about this problem, except maybe [this article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1196463), but it's behind a paywall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this issue as well. I got around it with this hack:

```
echo 'ZONE=management' >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
```

I'd prefer something more elegant but have settled on that for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: "Do not use it, it does not work"

Resolution

- During installation, or when %post script is executed, locks are not enabled, also required services are not running. That environment is anaconda execution environment and when one does chroot it to the installed machine, the same running environment is used with mount-bind-d pseudo filesystems.
- Due to lack of such setup environment during anaconda execution, there are problems with nmcli execution. Not everything works in %post section of kickstart as it works on fully functional running machine, you might be facing this problems.
- The better way is to run this once the machine is rebooted and fully functional post installation. One can also put this in some kind of firstboot logic(firstboot systemd unit) if you want.

So nmcli is good tool for network config automation.
You can use is for every purpose, except for installation.